# Uwp Prism No Viewmodel Locator

Tags: uwp, prism, uwp-xaml

If I want to use a page viewmodel and reference child viewmodels as properties of the parent how do I associate the child view to child viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a data template containing the child view for the child view model.

Edit: navigating view model-first is perfectly fine in a mvvm-context. In fact, one could argue that the view model locator may be bad style... but it is so handy and so widely used today, that it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Ah like this https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/ uwp mvvm is much more difficult that WinForms.

Comment: That depends - have you tried unit testing a win forms app that's basically only code behind?